# Bypassing Qt signaling to avoid class-to-class signaling

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I'm trying to figure out how I could work with Qt signals in a little bit different way.
I have a working example of such:

```
Game::Game(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
    , m_timer{nullptr}
{
  m_timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Game::run);
  m_timer->setinterval(300);
  m_timer->start();
}
```

Above signaling works fine and calls the Game::run regularly as desired. Now I am trying to replicate this with this bypass (for the sake of learning and it could be useful for more complicated moments especially in unit testing)

Abstract class:

```
class ISignalHandler
{
public:
    virtual void onTimeout() = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~ISignalHandler() = default;
};
```

and another class MyTimer.cpp:

```
MyTimer::MyTimer(QTimer *parent)
    : QTimer{parent}
{
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyTimer::onTimeout);
}

MyTimer::~MyTimer()
{
    delete m_timer;
    m_timer = nullptr;
}

void MyTimer::registerTimerSignal(ISignalHandler* callback)
{
    m_callback = callback;
}

void MyTimer::onTimeout()
{
    if (m_callback != nullptr)
    {
        m_callback->onTimeout();
    }
}
```

and finally Game class:

```
//header:
class Game : public QObject, public ISignalHandler
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Game(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Game();
//cpp:
        Game::Game(QObject *parent)
            : QObject{parent}
            , m_timer{nullptr}
        {
          m_timer = new MyTimer();
          m_timer->registerTimerSignal(this);
          m_timer->setinterval(300);
          m_timer->start();
        }

    void Game::onTimeout()
    {
        run();
    }
```

I expected that the MyTimer class will repeat within itself, and the signal will be handled to Game class so ::run will be continuously called. Where is a mistake here?

Comment: It seems `MyTimer` is derived from `QTimer` so you should connect `MyTimer::timeout` itself with `onTimeout` : `connect(this, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyTimer::onTimeout);`. `mTimer` with this approach is just useless and can be deleted from `MyTimer` class. `m_timer->start();` starts `m_timer` timer not `m_timer` as data member of `MyTimer` class - this is your issue.

Comment: @rafix07 is right. You've got redundant QTimers. The MyTimer class appears to be derived from QTimer, and you also have a member pointer that is a QTimer. In your Game constructor, you are calling setInterval() and start() on the base class QTimer. But the signal is connected to the member pointer.